# Not saving to db if form input fields are empty?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, save

I have created Wordpress custom fields through functions.php. My code works fine, and I've few input fields and some checkboxes.

Problem is when I save post, even if I don't put content inside my form, these rows are created in DB. I'd like to do some kind of php check and avoid creation of row in DB if field content is not saved.

I tried several ways, but in most cases it would result in incorrect behaviors of checkboxes for example.

Full code is here: http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=Vvnseiep

I'd appreciate your help in this matter. I'm not very experienced.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here Validation part comes into play. Why cant you use Javascript to validate your input in the client environment itself and then allowing it to hit the db.

Answer (score 0):

Name all of the checkboxes the same(`name="meta_box_check[]"`).  They must still have different ID's.  When the form is posted you will be given an array of values that were checked in `$_POST['meta_box_check']`.  You can then check if the array is empty.  You can also save the checkbox data as JSON data.  This isn't always good practice, but will only use one data row to save any and all checkbox values.

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['meta_box_check']))
{ 
   //process your data and save it
   update_post_meta($post_id, 'meta_features_checklist', json_encode($_POST['meta_box_check']));
}
?>
```

This is a basic example and make sure you do some data validating before saving.